# Вернуть из функции два массива

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Есть некоторая функция записи строки в двумерный массив строк, которая выделяет память под строку и записывает в еще один массив длину этой строки. Нужно вернуть из функции два массива: сам двумерный массив строк и массив длин строк. Подскажите пожалуйста как это можно сделать?

```
char write_str(char*str, int len, char**mass_str, int*mass_len, int n)//принимает строку, ее длину, двумерный массив строк, массив длин строк и некий индекс
{

    if (str[0] == ' ')//если в строке первый элемент - пробел, то его удаляем
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
        {
            str[i] = str[i + 1];
        }
        len--;
    }

    mass_len = (int*)realloc(mass_len, (n + 1) * sizeof(int));//записываем длину строки в массив длин
    mass_len[n] = len;

    mass_str = (char**)realloc(mass_str, (n + 1) * sizeof(char*));//выделяем память в массиве строк
    mass_str[n] = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)//записываем строку в массив строк
    {
        mass_str[n][i] = str[i];
    }

    return(*mass_str, *mass_len);//нужно вернуть два массива
}
```

Comment: Передавать через указатели - вы же все равно меняете переданное? В стиле трехзвездочного программиста - `char***mas_str, int**mas_len`. Но терзают меня смутные сомнения, что с таким вариантом, где массив указателей выделяется динамически, а потом элементам присваиваются другие указатели - очень легко запутаться, что надо освобождать, а что нет... Мне кажется, что вам ст*о*ит подумать над своим проектом (не над кодом, именно над проектом).

Comment: (а) Никогда не делайте `foo = realloc(foo, ...)`. (б) Весь вот этот огород с копированием строки поменяйте на `strdup()`.

Comment: А по сути вопроса, создаёте структуру данных, и не морочите голову ни с двойными, ни с тройными указателями. Достаточно одного указателя на структуру (объект структуры) данных.